# Meteor, get LoginWithService data without creating account

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

In Meteor, how can I proceed with LoginWithService (or LinkWithService) and get the service data without actually creating an account?

In my app, I use the service API keys to do certain tasks, to do that I use LinkWithService()

But I also allow users to login/create accounts with LoginWithService() function. But these two functions conflict with each other because if an account already exists with password + service, it will force a log out followed by another log-in.

I'm not sure if that made sense, anyhow I would like to just get the login service data without actually creating an account. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of this? `loginWithService` stores a section in the user's document under the `services` section, i.e `facebook`. It doesn't sound like its possible to get a conflict with two different users for the same account for the service in question - since passwords are stored in a different section `password`.